# gSOAP Server and Client within a Same Module

Tags: c++, linux, soap, gsoap

I want the application to be both a soap server and soap client, how to do that? How to handle below issue?

Suppose the soap Server provides ServiceA and the soap Client will access ServiceB in remote machine, and the skeleton files can be generated from ServiceA.h and ServiceB.h.

The problem is generating the Server code from Service.h and generating client code from ServiceB.h, they both produce three files: soapC.h, soapC.cpp, soapStub.h. As they are within a same project, they will conflict with each other. How to solve this?

Comment: You need to combine three files in one, and then generate soapC.h, soapH.h etc using soapcpp2 options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I took is to Use wsdl2h option -qname to generate definitions of different services into separate C++ name namespaces.

See the chapter **How to Build a Client or Server in a C++ Code Namespace** in this [gSOAP Manual](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.35)

Answer (score 0):

I got Segmentation.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0806642c in soap_getattrval ()
#1  0x08066ebc in soap_peek_element ()
#2  0x080658f7 in soap_element_begin_in ()
#3  0x08071e9d in soap_envelope_begin_in ()
#4  0x0034f449 in soap_call_ns1__MoperationC (
```